# How to add eclipseLink to netbeans 12?

Tags: netbeans, eclipselink

I want to use JPA in my Maven web application in netbeans 12.

So, I added in  the dependencies folder the following:
[image]

And now I try to add eclipseLink to my project. So I try to create the persistence.xml file in META-INF, so I get the following where I cannot click finish:
[image]

Please any advice to solve this issue.

If I try to create directly the entity I get the same above dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to select `Database Connection` to finish this dialog.